# How to redirect a URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, silverstripe

I have a problem in redirecting a URL on a Silverstripe website. I have a news feed page with a summary of articles in a paginated style. It displays 20 articles initially and switches to the next 20 based on the page number chosen. It is just the standard blog layout. When I click on page 2 then it should navigate to https://*****/news/?count=20 and for page 3 as https://*****/news/?count=40 etc. However upon clicking the blog page number it navigates to https://*****/news/news/?count=20. So the navigation link is not rewriting the parent URL.

All of my other Silverstripe websites work fine with the same blog layout except this and I don't see any reason to tweak the default code. I thought of adding a .htaccess redirect like this

```
Redirect 301 /news/news/?start=20 https://******/news/?start=20
```

but I didn't have any luck to make it work. Kindly suggest me a solution for this.

The output I expect is to redirect to the right URL

```
https://******/news/?start=20
```

Comment: Please understand that the query string (the part following the question mark) is _not_ part of the URL the rewriting pattern is applied against. So you redirection will never get applied.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Could you suggest me a solution to redirect URL despite the query string params. I just want one /news/ to be gone.

Comment: I added a short answer.

Comment: Seems you have one URL generated relative and not absolutely? This would explain the doubled `news`in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple redirection rule that should fix the symptom you describe:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?news/news/(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I doubt that approach is a good idea. Simply because it tries to fix a symptom, not the cause. The cause is that you actually create requests to URLs that contain the `/news/news/` issue which should never happen. I assume the cause of that issue is that you hand out *relative* references (so something like `news/...`) instead of *absolute* references (`/news/...`). I strongly suggest that you handle the cause instead of trying to fix the symptom.

Comment: Thanks. I will find the cause for this.